Is $\vec E$ more effective than $\vec B$ and why?
While reading about the Poynting vector in Optics (5 ed) by Eugene Hecht, I found the following line in page 42, from chapter 3.

Since, as we have learned, $\vec E$ is considerably more effective at exerting forces and doing work on charges than is $\vec B$, we shall refer to $\vec E$ as the optical field ...

What does the author mean by $\vec E$ is more effective than $\vec B$? My guess is that it has to do with their magnitudes in a electromagnetic wave, given that $E=cB$ for a e-m wave in vacuum.

A magnetic field does no work on a moving charge since the force it exerts is perpendicular to the charge’s velocity.

For free particles, perhaps this makes sense, but if you have wires to channel current $\vec B$ can be very effective. In technology, we commonly use magnets to move things and transmit power.

The force on a charge from the electric field is $\mathbf{F}_E = q\mathbf{E}$ and from the magnetic field is $\mathbf{F}_B = q\mathbf{v}\times \mathbf{B}$. If $E = cB$, as in an EM wave, we see that $F_B \le (v/c) F_E$. So unless your charges are moving at relativistic speeds, $F_E$ dominates $F_B$.

Makes sense, that would explain the force part. And what about the better efficiency at doing work? Is that because $\vec B$ is orthogonal to the trayectory of the charge?

Note that $||E||/||B||$ is a unit system dependent thing, e.g in Gaussian units a stat-volt per cm is a gauss. But the force ratio being $v/c$ isn't, and yes force being parallel to field and independent of velocity is easier to handle.
